# 'PERCENT_RANK' is not a recognized built-in function name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2012 which is supposed to have this built-in function (it even preempts the text when I type `PERCENT_`) however when I try to apply it it fails.

I believe my syntax is correct as it is working for other ranking and n-tiling functions.

In any case here it is:

```
PERCENT_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH, SEGMENT ORDER BY SALES/NULLIF(ORDERS,0) DESC) AS PTILE
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you are running SQL Server 2012? What do you get when you run `SELECT @@VERSION`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.  You need to look at the compatibility level that you are using:

```
select compatibility_level
from sys.databases;
```

Because the functionality was introduced in SQL Server 2012, you need a level of 110 or above.

The compatibility allows newer versions of SQL Server to emulate previous versions.  This can be handy when you need to run code that uses obsoleted features, for instance.

Comment: This is not too long for a comment at all, there's space for another 300+ chars.

Comment: Well you can't get syntax highlighting but you can still write `select compatibility_level
from sys.databases`