# SQL Server 2014 wrong compatibility level

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, which I supposed it had the compatibility level 110, but when trying to use `PERCENT_RANK()` function, I get an error

> 'PERCENT_RANK' is not a recognized built-in function name

I tried to change the compatibility level.

Here the options of compatibility levels available at options menu from database:

[image]

Any help so I can use the functionality from 110 version?

Comment: The compatibility level of support will depend on the database engine you are querying not the version of Mgmt Studio you are using, I think

Comment: The compatibility level is a database property, it's not affected by the SSSM version you use. You *don't* need to set a compatibility level at all to use windowing functions

Comment: SSMS 2014 supports SQL Server 2008-2014. SSMS 2018 supports SQL Server 2008+. Just because you're using SSMS 2014 doesn't mean you are using a **supported** version of SQL Server. Find out by running `PRINT @@VERSION;`.

Comment: `PERCENT_RANK` was introduced in SQL Server 2016. The screenshot suggest you use *SQL Server 2008 or 2008R2*, not 2014 as the 2012 compatibility level is missing.

Comment: SQl Server 2008 is completely out of support. If you *are* using it, and you do **need** more recent functions, it looks like your in need for that upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check which version of SQL Server you are running:

```
SELECT @@VERSION AS 'SQL Server Version';
```

Then check the compatibility level:

```
SELECT compatibility_level
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name = 'database name';
```

Set the name as the compatibility level can be different for each database.

Finally, you can set the compatibility level using a script:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename  
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 120;  
GO
```

Or using database properties in SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1):

The functionality was introduced in SQL Server 2012, you need a level of 110 or above. This is not dependent on your Mangament studio version but on the SQL Server version.
please see ['PERCENT_RANK' is not a recognized built-in function name in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43095423/percent-rank-is-not-a-recognized-built-in-function-name-in-sql-server)